# YARN or HDFS logs in Filebeat

Tags: hdfs, logstash, logstash-configuration, filebeat

If I want to ingest logs which are present in **HDFS** into **Filebeat**, how can i do that? I can specify any directory that will be on local drives but i want the Filebeat to pick data from HDFS. Is there any way this can be done? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Filebeat only reads files from local file system. One option may be using **HDFS NFS Gateway.** By this HDFS file system can be mounted as part of the client's local file system. [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.4/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsNfsGateway.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can mount `HDFS` to local file system, follow instructions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235198/mounting-of-hdfs-to-local-directory-failing) answer.